# Как получить элемент через value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Есть ссылка вида -

```
<a class="ui_actions_menu_item" onclick="alert('gh')" tabindex="0" role="link">
Видалити запис
</a>
```

Мне надо получить все ссылки в которых значение -  `"Видалити запис"`

Answer (score 1):

Берем все ссылки и фильтруем по содержимому

```
const links = [...document.querySelectorAll('a')].filter(a => {
    return a.innerHTML === 'Видалити запис'
})
```

Comment: Может проще через ```document.links```?